# https://www.blender.org/download/ vs https://download.blender.org

Tags: documentation

I had seen that there are two sites for blender with the term "download" in it, I know that https://www.blender.org/download/ is what's usually used for downloads so what is the other for?

Thank you

Comment: Hello :). "download.blender.org" is a blender.org subdomain with an [archive of all released](https://download.blender.org/release/) Blender versions.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.blender.org/download/ is a download hub for users to browse many versions of Blender, including the [latest stable version](https://www.blender.org/download/), [long-term support](https://www.blender.org/download/lts/), and [previous versions](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/). However, the files to be downloaded are not hosted on that path. Instead, the user will be redirected to one of the external mirror sites to download the files from there instead.

https://download.blender.org is one of the [external download mirrors](https://www.blender.org/about/website/) that actually hosts the files for users to download them from.